# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource error while upgrading to spring 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have upgraded spring-test version to 5.1.0 in my springboot project and I have controller test with @WebMvcTest failing with the below exceptions. Am I missing any dependencies?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = HGVSRestApiController.class, secure = false)
public class RestApiControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

Please help.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.instantiateListeners(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:186)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.getTestExecutionListeners(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:170)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:140)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.collectWrappedRunners(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:86)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.getClassesRequest(JUnit46ClassesRequestBuilder.java:47)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:46)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have also added the below dependency but it dint work

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>com.study</groupId>
        <artifactId>test_component</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <start-class>com.study.TestStarter</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <assembly_build_version>2.3.523</assembly_build_version>
        <descriptorRef>${svc_install_pkg}</descriptorRef>
        <!-- Additionally, Please make sure that your JAVA_HOME is pointing to 
            1.8 when building on commandline -->
        <skip_tomcat_bundle>false</skip_tomcat_bundle>

        <tomcat_bundle>tomcat85_24.tgz</tomcat_bundle>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
        <!-- Adds Tomcat and Spring MVC, along others -->
        <!--dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin><!-- Include if you want to make an executable jar[FAT JAR which 
                    includes all dependencies along with sprinboot loader] that you can run on 
                    commandline using java -jar NAME -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
              <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>target/hgvs-${project.version}.jar</file>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is there any missing dependencies? 
Your help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: please provide your pom.xml as well

Comment: updated the post with pom.xml

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing jars from different Spring and Spring Boot versions, things like that are trouble waiting to happen. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework, that will be the cause of many issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below dependency ,if it is not already present in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

From your stack trace it is seen that

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource
```

so the dependency might be **missing**, or since you recently upgraded the version for spring, this might be causing some incompatible version issues for your Transaction dependency.Try adding the above dependency to resolve that.Check your dependencies to verify that you are not referencing any old jars that pull in this particular dependency, if so check why it is not pulling this dependency after the upgrade.

If you are using **spring-boot** , then this **dependency** should be part of `spring-boot-autoconfigure` or `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

A NoClassDef error is generally when you do have the class during compile time but it isn't present during runtime. Please check your maven dependencies thoroughly for any jar conflicts. This might be a possible cause for the NoClassDef. Check your pom.xml and navigate to the dependency hierarchy tab to verify if you do not see the same jar with different versions twice.

If you have conflicts you can then remove one of them depending on the version that you require.

> A project's dependency tree can be expanded to display dependency
>   conflicts. For example, to find out why Commons Collections 2.0 is
>   being used by the Maven Dependency Plugin, we can execute the
>   following in the project's directory:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

Refer [Official Doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Make sure you include only one `spring-tx` as dependency,if you have more than one added as transitive dependency you can make exception like :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added spring-tx dependency but it still failed. I have added pom in my description.

Comment: What you are probably having in conflicting dependencies.I have updated the answer.