# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext error while running controller test

Tags: spring

I am currently experiencing problems with running WebMvcTest for controller class in a springboot2x project...

why this exception is thrown? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I have also tried to add mockito-core 2x dependency but didnt work.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.task.execution-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeansOfType(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Map;
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>





    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
        <!-- Adds Tomcat and Spring MVC, along others -->
        <!--dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin><!-- Include if you want to make an executable jar[FAT JAR which 
                    includes all dependencies along with sprinboot loader] that you can run on 
                    commandline using java -jar NAME -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
              <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-a-jar</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/HGVSRestApiApp.*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/HGVSRestApiController.*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>target/hgvs-${project.version}.jar</file>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = TestController.class, secure = false)
public class TestController{

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    TestController controller;

    @MockBean
    TestService testService;
```

The above controller test is not working and thrwoing expcetion.
Thanks!

Comment: The erroris because spring is trying to invoke  qualifiedBeansOfType method of BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils, but it is included as of Spring 5.1.1

Comment: I tried again after changing spring version to 5.1.5 but this didnt work

Comment: try adding the dependency, i think  other dependency is overriding it         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: started throwing new error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlProcessor$StrictMapAppenderConstructor

Comment: I have updated spring version 5.1.0 for other spring lib and spring-boot version 1.4.3 and still throwing the above exception. I dont understand why it throws it even there is dependency present

Comment: You are mixing jars of different spring versions, hence issues. Don't mix versions of a framework, that is trouble waiting to happen.  Remove the `spring-aop`, `spring-test`, `junit`, `mockito` dependencies. Replace the `spring-boot-starter-test-autoconfigure` with just `spring-boot-starter-test` to have all the proper dependencies.

Comment: This is basically the same issue as you have in your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138441/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-transaction-interceptor-tran). Again/still your dependencies (and plugins) are a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by upgrading to springboot 2 using this article:
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4842-3165-4%2F1.pdf